# Ionic - Mudar cor da barra superior do aplicativo

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Ionic3 e quando inicio o app no emulador roda bacana, porém é comum nos aplicativos a barra preta ficar na cor do header porém em um tom mais escuro. Como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra coisa, quando simulo no iOS a barra superior fica sobre os elementos da aplicação, como corrigir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desculpa perguntar em cima da sua pergunta, esse layout você que produziu ou é algo que já vem no ionic ... !!! eu mexo com angular e react e sempre temos que instalar  kkk

Comment: Olá, o layout deste header (botões, seachbar e carrinho) foi criado por mim, porém utiliza-se de componentes prontos do Ionic, a propriedade de posicionamento do elemento é do proprio framework (utilizo Start e End para posicionar os elementos), alguma estilização como no caso do balão do carrinho fiz manualmente (SCSS), mas os componentes são praticamente prontos para uso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode alterar a cor da barra superior e corrigir a barra no IOS com o plugin `cordova-plugin-statusbar`. Inclua no `config.xml` a propriedade `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` para alterar a cor e a `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` como false para que o menu superior não fique sobre seu app no IOS.

Instale o plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

Inclua no app.module.ts:

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
...
providers: [
  StatusBar,
...
```

Inclua no config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Olá Renata, obrigado pelo retorno, realizei o procedimento conforme orientado, porém o teste com "ionic serve --lab" não mostra a alteração. Acho que terei que instalar um emulador para a plataforma desejada (android e iOs), vc utiliza algum específico, qual?

Comment: Um dos emuladores que eu uso é o [Ionic DevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/), que é um aplicativo que você instala no seu celular. Conectando o celular na mesma rede que o seu computador, digite ionic serve -c na linha de comando. O Ionic DevApp é muito útil para testar alguns plugins nativos.

Comment: Valeu Renata, estou fazendo os testes aqui, muito obrigo pelo direcionamento.